# my strings will not be re-declared in my loop

Tags: javascript

I have been programming a Battlesnake (https://play.battlesnake.com/) and I need to re-declare my move commands (like `move="left"` and `move="right"` for example)  command but every time it goes over the code it uses the move command once and won't use it again. It also only uses the first one it can and won't use any other ones above it. Loops won't work because to my understanding the Battlesnake servers call the `handleMove` function each turn and if the Battlesnake servers don't get a response within 500 milliseconds the game will move for you. The code starts at the top of the `handleMove` and ends at the `response.status` thing. I know the code goes through the functions because I tracked it with `console.log`. The code goes through everything as intended, because I set `console.log` on all of the functions and inside all the if commands, and it runs through the move strings inside the if commands, but ignores all move commands it reaches after the code gets to `response.status`.  That is where I am confused. A lot of the data is hosted on the Battlesnake servers, so if something is not declared in my code it probably came from the Battlesnake servers.
How can I fix this?

```
const express = require('express')

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.get('/', handleIndex)
app.post('/start', handleStart)
app.post('/move', handleMove)
app.post('/end', handleEnd)

app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Battlesnake Server listening at http://127.0.0.1:${PORT}`))


function handleIndex(request, response) {
  var battlesnakeInfo = {
    apiversion: '1',
    author: '',
    color: '#1c607d',
    head: 'caffeine',
    tail: 'leaf'
  }
  response.status(200).json(battlesnakeInfo)
}

function handleStart(request, response) {
  var gameData = request.body

  console.log('START')
  response.status(200).send('ok')
}

function handleMove(request, response) {
  var gameData = request.body
  var head = gameData.you.head
  var boardWidth = gameData.board.width
  var boardHeight = gameData.board.height
  var food = gameData.board.food[0]

  // code i wrote

  function moveUpB() {

    if (head.x < 1) {

      move = "up"
      //refuses to execute at all??
    }


  }


  function moveRightB() {

    if (head.y > (boardHeight - 2)) {

      move = "right"
      //only used once
    }

  }

  function moveDownB() {

    if (head.x > (boardWidth - 2)) {

      move = "down"
      //only used once
    }

  }

  function moveLeftB() {

    if (head.y < 1) {

      move = "left"
      //only used once
    }

  }


  moveUpB()

  moveRightB()

  moveDownB()

  moveLeftB()
  //aafter here it should go back to moveUpB but it doesent?



  //rest of the code needed for the snake to move
  console.log('MOVE: ' + move)



  response.status(200).send({
    move: move




  })

}





function handleEnd(request, response) {
  var gameData = request.body

  console.log('END')
  response.status(200).send('ok')
}
```

Comment: response.status.send sends the response over http to the client. Now the client needs to make another request. There is no loop.

Comment: then how do i fix it?